# How much tax does each zoned building generate?

Tags: cities-skylines

How much tax does each growable building generate? I am aware that higher level buildings genereate "more" taxes. But how can I determine how much money one specific factory/store/residence is generating each week?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible to see how much income a specific building generates. The highest level of detail you can see is the weekly income for zones and levels of a specific building type. You can view this information in the Economy menu specifically by hovering over the type of interest.

For example here is the weekly income breakdown for industrial levels and specializations.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to determine exactly what the building can produce, as there are many factors that play into it, including;

- Pollution
- Noise Pollution
- Goods available
- Education progress
- Leisure
- Public transportation or trains
- Fire, health, police, garbage coverage

There are also a few other factors such as the building itself, it's level, and the amount of residents inside the building. This means it is not possible to exactly know what the tax income generated by these buildings is.